# SQL JOIN with multiple date condition

Tags: sql, join

We have the first **valuetable** table and the query should check if there is
a next younger datetime in the **correctiontable** table and should add the **corrvalue** with the **corrdatetime**.

My problem query:

```
SELECT * FROM valuetable vt
LEFT JOIN correctiontable corr ON corr.value_id = vt.id WHERE vt.datetime <= corr.corrdatetime
```

is just delivering the last corrdatetime...

To clarify te results:

- **Row1 id1** should be NULL as the valuetable datetime is younger than the correction datetime
- **Row2 id2** should be *01/08/2017 00:00:00* as the datetime in valuetable is older but younger than the *01/12/2017 10:00:00* corrdatetime
- **Row3 id2** got its correction on *01/12/2017 10:00:00*
- **Row4 id3** is NULL, there is no corrdatetime in correctiontable for it

Thank you all ++

```
+----------------------------------+
|            valuetable            |
+----------------------------------+
| id | datetime            | value |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 1  | 22/07/2017 13:00:00 | 123   |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 2  | 10/08/2017 09:00:00 | 456   |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 2  | 05/12/2017 20:00:00 | 789   |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 3  | 11/11/2017 11:11:11 | 012   |
+----+---------------------+-------+
```

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                 correctiontable                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| id | value_id | corrdatetime        | corrvalue |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 1  | 2        | 01/08/2017 00:00:00 | 888       |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 2  | 2        | 01/12/2017 10:00:00 | 999       |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| 3  | 1        | 01/08/2017 20:00:00 | 111       |
+----+----------+---------------------+-----------+
```

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                               Result (as it should be)             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | datetime            | corrdatetime        | value | corrvalue |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-----------+
| 1  | 22/07/2017 13:00:00 | NULL                | 123   | NULL      |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-----------+
| 2  | 10/08/2017 09:00:00 | 01/08/2017 00:00:00 | 456   | 888       |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-----------+
| 2  | 05/12/2017 20:00:00 | 01/12/2017 10:00:00 | 789   | 999       |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-----------+
| 3  | 11/11/2017 11:11:11 | NULL                | 012   | NULL      |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "younger" means "logically less than", this should work for you.

```
select *
    from valuetable a
    outer apply (
        select top 1 *
            from correctiontable y
            where y.value_id = a.id
                and y.datetime < a.datetime
            order by y.datetime desc
    ) b
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks to @KindaTechy for delivering me the right path!

I've created two querys, one for MySQL and one for >= Oracle 12.1

***For MySQL:***

```
SELECT *
  FROM valuetable vt
  LEFT JOIN correctiontable ON correctiontable.id
    =
    (SELECT corr.id
     FROM correctiontable corr
     WHERE vt.id = corr.value_id
      AND vt.datetime <= corr.corrdatetime
     ORDER BY datetime DESC
     LIMIT 1)
```

***For Oracle:***

```
select *
    from valuetable vt
    outer apply (
        select *
            from correctiontable corr
            where corr.value_id = vt.id
                and corr.corrdatetime < vt.datetime
            order by corr.corrdatetime desc
            FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) b;
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a working query, but your `id` column of `valuetable` should be unique, because otherwise you get a cross product.

```
SELECT vt.id, vt.datetime, corr.corrdatetime, vt.value, corr.corrvalue
FROM valuetable vt
LEFT JOIN correctiontable corr 
ON corr.value_id = vt.id
AND vt.datetime >= corr.corrdatetime
```

By changing the date constraint from `WHERE-CLAUSE` to `ON-CLAUSE` it will impact only the join and not the result.

A made a sample for you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/301a6/4/0

**When** you need that non-unique id, the query must be improved. And also the test data set.

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output that the user has indicated

Comment: Thank you Nachtgold for your work, but KindaTechy is right on that.